# C - "sysmalloc: Assertion ..." error for some sizes

Tags: c, memory, runtime-error

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* text1 = "This is a string.";
char* text2 = "Yet another thing.";

void copyCodes (int* list, char* text){
  while(*text != 0){
    *list = *text;
    list++;
    text++;
  }
  *(list+sizeof(int)) = 0;
}

int main(void){
  int size = 72; //THIS IS THE ERROR
  int* list1 = malloc(size);
  int* list2 = malloc(size);

  copyCodes(list1, text1);
  copyCodes(list2, text2);

  free(list1);
  free(list2);
}
```

The code above **does** work.
However, if i change the `size` to any value between 72 and 89 *(excluding 72 and 89)* i get an `sysmalloc: Assertion ...` error.

Why?

**Note**
Error occurs on my Ubuntu (16.04) machine, but it works fine on my OSX (10.11.5) machine.

**Full error**

```
malloc.c:2395: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Edit1**
Worth noting, the code works when written in MIPS assembly and allocating 80 bytes of memory for each array. (The C code above is an exact translation of the assembly instructions).

Comment: Ia this the *full* code?

Comment: @EugeneSh.Yeah. (I removed everything unnecessary).

Comment: you've got UB here: `*(list+sizeof(int)) = 0;`: offset is +4 and you already passed the string. You actually add 16. 72+16 = 88 is the minimum you need.

Comment: You might *wrongly* think it is unnecessary. Does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: OK, nvm. @Jean-FrançoisFabre have nailed it...

Comment: @EugeneSh. the error remains the same. Same message, same conditions for failure / success.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you invoke *undefined behavior* when you write beyond the end of the allocated space here:

```
*(list+sizeof(int)) = 0;
```

With the second string, which is 18 characters, `list` gets incremented 18 times, and assuming 4 byte ints, now points one past the end of the 72 bytes allocated. Then you do the above, which writes at offset 72 + `sizeof(int)` * `sizeof(*list)` == 72 + 16.

BTW, "Works fine" only means "I'm blissfully unaware what bug is waiting to happen".

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the last instruction of `copyCodes`

```
void copyCodes (int* list, char* text){
  while(*text != 0){
    *list = *text;
    list++;
    text++;
  }
  *(list+sizeof(int)) = 0;
}
```

first string has a size of 17. So you need to allocate (17+1)*4 = 72 bytes all right (null termination is copied), *but* in the end, you zero a zone which is at offset 72+16 (because of pointer arithmetic, +sizeof(int) adds +4 (if `int` is size 4).

Note that the second string has a size of 18, and even 72 bytes don't suffice since you copy the null termination char.

Why it is working for 72 is because of luck, but safely need at least 72+16+4 = 92 bytes allocated to make this work safely:

the actual formula would be:

```
(strlen(text)+sizeof(int)+1)*sizeof(int)
```

needed bytes.

but I just suspect that `*(list+sizeof(int)) = 0;` is a typo/useless code, because the area in-between has undefined values. Remove it and you only need

```
(strlen(text)+1)*sizeof(int)
```

needed bytes (I suppose it was to null-terminate the integer list but the null termination char is already copied by your while loop)